# Можно ли в произвольном тексте найти все, что закодировано в Base64?

Tags: c#, .net, base64

Например, имеется произвольный текст, где могут встречаться последовательности, которые закодированы в base64.

Можно ли из текста получить все эти последовательности какой-нибудь регуляркой?

Как я понял, иногда происходит с использованием пробелов=> нужно пониматься, что 2 последовательности, которые разделены пробелом относятся к одной закодированной информации.

Comment: Ну, хм. Вот например текст `Rindfleischetikettierungsueberwachungsaufgabenuebertragungsgesetz` — это base64 или нет? (Это немецкое слово, в общем-то.)

Comment: Любую последовательность из 4 символов, разрешённых в BASE64, можно декодировать как 3 байта.

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать частотный анализ